# Unreadable font in QGIS on Ubuntu?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, font

I am new to Ubuntu, so forgive me if this a very standard question:
I installed QGIS 2.18 and all seems to work well. However, there is a major issue: the program uses a very strange font so I can't read anything? I tried to find something on the internet, but none seem to have the same issue.

As I do not now much about Ubuntu, my trouble-shooting-abilities are very low.

Is there a workaround to change the font in QGIS so I can get started working with it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see you're using LXDE. Do you have any other window managers installed which you can try? Are any other Qt based applications affected?

I suspect this is might be an issue with Qt and your window manager than QGIS specifically, so if this doesn't work you might want to try on Ask Ubuntu or SuperUser.

You could try changing the font in the **settings > options** menu. You could also try changing the **Style** option (GTK+, Mosaic, etc.).

I suspect the font is Dingbats. As this isn't readable, you can find these settings...

- the fifth menu from the left, and
- the second last menu item. Should see something like this.
- you may need to use the horizontal scroll bar to see the combo box.
- the pull down list of fonts should be readable for some (but not all) fonts.

[image]

Although with Dingbats it may look like ...

[image]

If you change the **Style** you'll need to restart QGIS, but font changes should take place immediately.

Comment: Very precise, thank you very much! I still wonder why I had Dingbats as default...
Other programs than QGIS worked fine, so far (however, I didn't try that many)